# How to make custom plugin for CkEditor 5 React(TypeScript)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I use **CkEditor 5 with React(TypeScript)** and I want to make a custom plugin for Import Video.
I found many posts about JavaScript, but I need **TypeScript**.
Does anyone know how to make a custom plugin?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site to get help with your existing code, not to help you design something that you haven't yet designed.  
If you don't have current code, nor do you know how you'd design this on paper regardless of code implementation, then you need to do [additional research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before posting here. 
If you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried.

Comment: First result on google, not sure if it can help: https://gist.github.com/ExploreHW/7b2b6f04e8124292956b4832e643c80b